# Super classes are instatiated multiple times when test packages are executed using TestNG

Tags: testing, testng

I am seeing a behavior with TestNG which I am not sure is correct.
I have two classes ClassA extends ClassB

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB{

    static {
        System.out.println("Static Initialization block : Init CLass A");
    }

    ClassA(){
        System.out.println("inside ClassA constructor");
    }

    @Test
    public void testme() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Test Case");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class ClassB{
    static {
        System.out.println("Static Initialization block : Init CLass B");
    }

    ClassB(){
        System.out.println("inside ClassB constructor");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(){
        System.out.println("ClassB setup");
    }
}
```

These classes are placed under com.test package

Now when I execute ClassA.java as a TestNG test from eclipse I get below output :

Static Initialization block : Init CLass B
Static Initialization block : Init CLass A
inside ClassB constructor
inside ClassA constructor

If I execute same code by selecting com.test package I seeing below output :

Static Initialization block : Init CLass B
inside ClassB constructor
Static Initialization block : Init CLass A
inside ClassB constructor
inside ClassA constructor

Basically, ClassB is getting instantiated twice when executed as a testNg package as ClassB contains @BeforeClass annotation, This is making my code to fail with Null pointer exceptions.

Am i missing any thing here ?

Thanks
CG

Answer (score 0):

When you are running it from the package, looks like both classes ClassA and ClassB are getting invoked by TestNG one by one.

First ClassB which gives you:

> Static Initialization block : Init CLass B inside ClassB constructor

Then ClassA which gives you:

> Static Initialization block : Init CLass A inside ClassB constructor
> inside ClassA constructor

---

Running it from the package is not the right way to run a TestNG. If you want to invoke only one class then running the same class as a TestNG run is fine but when you want to invoke more than one class you need to mention the sequence. TestNG.xml file can help you define those and run it. You can invoke it in different ways, Read More [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#introduction)